# remove tag with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and want to remove anchors without the ".primary-black" class e.g

```
var text = '<a class="primary-black" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>';
```

Result should be:

```
var text = '<a class="primary-black" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
Google';
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? To remove anchors without the `.primary-black` class?

Comment: yes exactly i want to remove anchors with out .primary-black class

Comment: The result string end with 'Google' , you want the content inside the anchor tag to remain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would have done it. You can use `unwrap` to remove the tags for those particular elements

```js
var x = $( "a:not(.primary-black)" ).contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="primary-black" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```js
var text = '<a href="" class="primary-black">G1</a><a href="" class="primarck">G2</a><a href="" class="primary-black">G3</a><a href="" class="primary-b">G4</a>';

var $div = $('<div>');
$div.append(text);
var $tags = $div.find('a:not(.primary-black)');
$tags.each(function() {
  var $tag = $(this);
  $tag.replaceWith($tag.text());
});
text = $div.html();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Every `<a>` element without class `primary-black` will be removed, but the contents will remain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

HTML

```
<a class="primary-black" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
if(element[index].className!="primary-black"){
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
    }
}
```

This will remove your anchor tag which is not having class primary-black.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = '<a class="primary-black" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>';
  var output = '';

  $(text).each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(value).is('a') && !$(value).hasClass('primary-black')) {
      output = output + value.innerHTML;
    } else {
      output = output + value.outerHTML;
    }
  });
  console.log(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```